# Enable/Disable Form List Field based on record attribute in parent table

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

There are two tables in my database: Add_New_Initiative and Add_Risk

There is a 1:M relationship between Add_New_Initiative and Add_Risk.

When adding a risk via the Add_Risk form, the user must select the related Initiative_ID from a drop down combo box.

Based on that selection, a value list titled Risk_Area, within the Add_Risk form, will either be enabled or disabled. To determine this, I need to look up the record by Initiative_ID and see what answer the user previously selected for a value list titled Tier, within the Add_New_Initiative form.

Logically, I see it playing out as such:

1. If Initiative_ID on Add_Risk form is Null, then Risk_Area will be disabled.
2. If Initiative_ID on Add_Risk form is not blank, then lookup the Tier value on the Add_New_Initiative form for the record with the Initiative_ID that the user entered/selected on the Add_Risk form.
3. If the Tier is 1 or 2, then Risk_Area will be enabled on the Add_Risk form.
4. If the Tier is 3 or Null, then Risk_Area will be disabled on the Add_Risk form.

When coding this in VBA, how would I reference the Tier value that is stored in the other Form/Table?

Comment: Where is your question? What has the Mysql tag have to do in the question?

Comment: The actual question would be helpful. My apologies. I have added it.

Comment: `Risk_Area.enabled = (tier = 1 or tier=2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the question, you are having trouble looking/referencing data in other tables.
Perform a dlookup to look for a specific value in a table/query.

```
dim VarTier as integer
VarTier = nz(Dlookup("Tier","Add_New_Initiative","Initiative_ID=" & me.Initiative_ID.value),-1)
```

Dlookup will return:

1. Null if there is no record found with matching criteria, which is handled by nz thus making VarTier into -1, so you can handle it with an if statement.
2. If a record with Initiative_ID equal to the Add_Risk form is found, it will return the value of Tier for that record.

Then you will have to compare the result of the lookup with a simple if.

```
If Vartier = 1 or VarTier = 2 then
    me.list.enabled = true
End If
```

More about Dlookup over here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/ff834404(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: `Private Sub Initiative_ID_AfterUpdate()

Dim varTier As Integer
varTier = Nz(DLookup("Tier", "New Initiatives", "Initiative_ID = " & Me.Initiative_ID.Value), -1)

If varTier = 1 Or varTier = 2 Then
    Me.Risk_Area.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.Risk_Area.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub`

Comment: I added an `Else me.list.enabled = false` before the End If and it always disables the list. If I swap the enable/disable, it always enables the list. I take that to mean that the varTier is always returning -1 and isn't capturing the value of the Tier field. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your guess is 99% correct. Dlookup is not finding matching record and is returning null. Double check inside the Dlookup that the parameter are exactly well written.  `Tier` should be exactly as the field name in table `New Initiatives`. Also, if `Initiative_ID` is text, me.Initiative_ID.value should be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Definitely a syntax error. The Initiative ID field doesn't contain an underscore, but I was including it in VBA. Changing it to a space with [ ] around it worked. Thanks for your help.